# Driver compatibility between distros

Tags: drivers, embedded

I am working on a project that will involve the communication between a data acquisition system (hardware) and a computer board called Beaglebone.
One of the hardware that I am evaluating said to have APIs for C (which I need, great) and driver support for Red Hat Enterprise 7. 
Now, this hardware is somewhat expensive. When I talked to the vendor he said that I should go for a different embedded system, making the whole setup more expensive (beaglebones are much cheaper than FPGAs). The reason, he said, is that would be risky because of the driver support in the beaglebone distribution. Nevertheless, I suspect that he may be pushing the expensive setup for other reasons.

I did a search around this and people usually say that if the kernel version of the target is newer than the support, there is a high chance that it will work. 
I am running Debian stretch 9.4 with kernel 4.9.0-6 on the beagle.
Red Hat enterprise 7 seems to be kernel 3.10.0-229.

What do you guys think?

Comment: How is the data acquisition system connected to the computer controlling it? USB? Do you know if “driver support for RHEL 7” means that it works with drivers included with RHEL 7, or that the hardware manufacturer provides a specific driver which works with RHEL 7?

Comment: Yes, USB. I could not get information regarding the second question, but I believe that they provide a specific driver. They even have their own software platform for communication between these hardware (LabView)

Answer (score 0):

When people say driver support you never know what you will get.

Linux drivers for a name brand UPS would only work with legacy serial ports (not USB) - I used gnut instead.

I got and SDK for a desktop RFID reader/writer and that was precompiled `.so` files for i586, not much use on ARM.

OTOH you can download the CUPS driver source for the citizen POS thermal printer driver and when built it will run on anything and work will most similar looking printers (does not so well on OSX for some reason).

Turbosight DVBS2 drivers - they seems to rely on patching the kernal source and deleting things that are incompatible... every time I upgrade the kernel in my PVR box I need to reboot, rebuild, reboot :(